# Get minecraft uuid by PHP script without API

Tags: java, php, uuid, minecraft

How to get Minecraft player `UUID` for players with UTF-8 names, such as "игрок"? Any known API works incorrectly in this case. All the more so, API uses connection with externally resources, as I want to use only one PHP script. In Java code of getting UUID of player is:

```
UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(("OfflinePlayer:" + name).getBytes(Charsets.UTF_8))
```

Need help for creating function analogue.

Comment: Are you asking how to translate that one line of Java you posted into PHP?

Comment: In Minecraft, all player names only allows `word characters`. This refers to `\w` in regex, and specifies on range `A-Z`, `a-z`, and underscore. You will _never_ be able to translate a `UUID` to a "UTF-8 name", because it doesn't happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no easy way to implement this behaviour in PHP as `nameUUIDFromBytes` relies on a 64-bit twos compliment integer for all its bitwise arithmetic, however PHP's integer are limited to the number of bits of the processor architecture - 32 for 32 and 64 for 64, so unless you can guarantee it will only be run on 64 bit systems, you'll have to find an arbitrary precision library to do it for you.

So instead, why don't you just wrap the PHP around the Java, for example, create a Jar file for this script:

```
package uuid;

import com.google.common.base.Charsets;
import java.util.UUID;

public class GetUUID
{
    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(("OfflinePlayer:" + args[0]).getBytes(Charsets.UTF_8)));
    }
}
```

Then have a PHP script which calls the Jar file, like this:

```
<?php

$username = @$_GET['username'];
if(empty($username))
{
    http_response_code(400);
    die;
}

echo exec("java -jar C:\UUID.jar $username");
?>
```

Then you can call the PHP script with `http://example.com/uuid.php?username=test`, which will produce:

> 530fa97a-357f-3c19-94d3-0c5c65c18fe8